# How to get meta data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, metadata, meta-boxes

I am creating a new wordpress plugin. But i have face some problem. I am using java script that needed to dynamic.

I have use:

```
    <script>
    var memoryval = new Array('<?php echo $feature_info_1; ?>', '2GB', '3GB', '4GB'); 

    </script>
```

I have create meta box field:

```
<input type="text" name="feature_info1_name" value="50GB" <?php echo $feature_info_1; ?> />
```

When I put some data in metabox field it will work via this script. But not work this script.

Actually I need to get data bellow value dynamically from meta box.

```
var memoryval = new Array('1GB', '2GB', '3GB', '4GB');
```

Help me any expert.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var memoryval = ['<?php echo $feature_info_1; ?>', '2GB', '3GB', '4GB'];
```

```html
<input type="text" name="feature_info1_name" value="<?php echo $feature_info_1; ?>" />
```

and it should be ok.

Comment: 'code' var memoryval = ['<br />  have been shown in source page

Comment: Please explain what your script is expected to do. What script are you talking about javascript or php ? Do you want javacript send to php or php feed javascript ? What does not work and what do you want to get ? May be you can show us your entire script for us to understand better.

Comment: did you take a look at this tuttorial ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530656/wordpress-meta-boxes-wp-tuts-tutorial?rq=1

Comment: Hello guys! problem solved by using 'var memoryval = jQuery("meta[feature_info1_name]");'